# textContent returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in which I want to extract the text of the active item. I do this with the following code:

```
    var addedWorkout = $("#custDropDownMenuA").find(".dropdown-item.active");
    console.log(addedWorkout);
    addedWorkout = addedWorkout.textContent;
    console.log(addedWorkout);
```

The problem is that I keep getting undefined. I checked the console and it indeed finds the element I want without fail.

[image]

I am relatively new to Javascript, but after over an hour of Googling I could not find the issue and I don't understand why. I know that I can get the text element if I hardcore it using the following line:

```
document.querySelector("#selectiona1").textContent
```

but not with:

```
$("#selectiona1").textContent
```

What is the difference between these 2? I read that textContent is part of the DOM, to my understanding it relates to objects and according to my console i think it is an object. I made some crazy attempts like putting the object I got into the querySelector, but nothing works.

Comment: `addedWorkout` is a jQuery object which doesn't have a `textContent` property. Either use `addedWorkout.text()` or (which is what I'd do) kick out jQuery because it's no longer needed for most DOM manipulation tasks.

Comment: Simply replace `var addedWorkout = $("#custDropDownMenuA").find(".dropdown-item.active");` by `var addedWorkout = document.querySelector("#custDropDownMenuA .dropdown-item.active");` and leave the rest as-is.

Comment: I suggest you learn the native DOM API over jQuery first. Turn to jQuery only where it really benefits you (which you won't know if you don't know the native DOM API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
var addedWorkout = $("#custDropDownMenuA").find(".dropdown-item.active");
```

you're using *jQuery* to select the `.dropdown-item.active` inside `#custDropDownMenuA`, and when you select with jQuery, you get a jQuery object in response. So, `addedWorkout` is  a jQuery object, and jQuery objects generally do not have the same properties/methods as standard HTMLElements. (`querySelector` is the vanilla Javascript method to retrieve an element)

Either select the `[0]`th item in the jQuery collection to get to the first matching element:

```
var addedWorkout = $("#custDropDownMenuA").find(".dropdown-item.active")[0];
```

Or use the jQuery method to get the text of the first matching element, which is `.text()`:

```
var addedWorkoutText = addedWorkout.text();
```

(note the use of a new variable - you will likely find it easier to read and debug code when you create new variables rather than reassigning old ones, when possible)

Answer (score 1):

Your var `'addedWorkout'` is a Jquery object, not a html element.

To show the text use:

```
addedWorkout.text();
```

Alternatively, you can change the `'addedWorkout'` to a html element by adding the index [0], like this:

```
addedWorkout[0].textContent;
```